# Usage of He/She asked or He/She said

Tags: grammar

I have been noticing in books that I have read lately that the authors are making a quote with a question mark, yet write: he said or she said instead of he asked or she asked.
Examples:
"How do you know?" Rina said.
"Any idea where he might have gone?" Rina said
Ezra said, "Did you check the house? Maybe he went home?"

Are these correct?

Comment: https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9931/why-do-writers-use-said-instead-of-asked-when-someone-asks-a-question  good complete answers there in that link and other links you can jump to from there at the site

Comment: well you already know they asked due to the question mark. Kind of like _"Wow!" she exclaimed._ I already knew she exclaimed because of the exclamation mark, so why wouldn't _"Wow!" she said._ be ok?